# Can I use Pro-Tools 9 on my PC and Mac

Tags: pro-tools, post-production, software, mac, pc

I am thinking moving to Pro Tools 9 soon, but I am unsure if I can register Pro tools 9 on both my PC and Mac, cause sometimes I need to work on both systems and its going to get messy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With iLok you can use it on both Systems, however, only one at a time.

Comment: I 2nd that answer. Install it on as many systems as you want but can only one at a time via iLok.